# Importing xml file to SQL Server with same format

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have been trying to import the ssis dtsx (xml file) to a SQL server table. The format is getting changed in table. like `<` in source file getting changed to `&lt;` and multiple lines in source becoming single line in target.

```
Create table #XMLFilesTable(XMLData xml)

INSERT INTO #XMLFilesTable(XMLData)
SELECT Convert(XML,BulkColumn) As BulkColumn
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Users\myFile.dtsx', Single_Blob) as Image
```

Is there any way to import the xml as is without change in target. I need this field as xml datatype in target. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear. But my magic crystal ball told me, that your issue might be in the way of reading the XML **after** the import.

If the snippet you provide really works, it seems to be possible to load the file's content into a natively XML typed column. If there were any issues with the file, the XML's format, the XML not being well formed - what ever - this would fail.

Due to obvious reasons there are some characters, which cannot be within an XML's content as they are used for the *markup* part, namely `<, > and &` (but there are more).

Such characters need escaping. In XML we speak about *entities*. Done properly all this magic is done implicitly and you should not have to bother about this at all.

Some possible ideas:

### Wrong encodig

The string `copy & paste` will translate to `copy &amp; paste`. I have seen cases, were the developers built the XML via string concatenation. If the value is pre-encoded (`copy &amp; paste`) but the XML's creation is changed to a real XML engine, you will get `copy &amp;amp; paste`

### Wrong reading

If the correctly encoded XML is read with string methods (`SUBSTRING` et al.), such encoded entities will remain as they are.

### `CDATA` sections

If your XML includes `CDATA` sections you will find, that the developers auf SQL Server decided not to support this any more. There is actually no reason for a `CDATA` because a properly escaped content is semantically identical:

```
<root><![CDATA[test with <, > and &]]></root>

is eaxctly the same as this

<root>test with &lt;, &gt; and &amp;</root>
```

`CDATA` sections are removed automatically. Try it out:

```
DECLARE @xml XML='<root><![CDATA[test with <, > and &]]></root>';
SELECT @xml;
```

### What you can do

It would help to provide a (reduced!) sample of your XML (some part with such characters).

If the XML is not double-encoded, I'm pretty sure your issue is on the reading side.

One example to check this out

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(100)='copy & paste';
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Explanation VARCHAR(100),theXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('encodig by engine'    ,(SELECT @value FOR XML PATH('root')))
                      ,('correct pre-encoding' ,'<root>copy &amp; paste</root>') 
                      ,('double encodig'       ,'<root>copy &amp;amp; paste</root>')
                      /*,('not well formed','<root>copy & paste</root>') --have to exclude this as it would fail*/
SELECT Explanation
      ,theXml
      ,theXml.value(N'(/root/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS TheContent
FROM @tbl
```

The result

```
Explanation              theXml                             TheContent
encodig by engine       <root>copy &amp; paste</root>       copy & paste
correct pre-encoding    <root>copy &amp; paste</root>       copy & paste
double encodig          <root>copy &amp;amp; paste</root>   copy &amp; paste
```

Finally a trick how you can "correct" a wrong result, if you cannot change the above:

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(100)='copy &amp; paste';
SELECT CAST('<x>' + @value + '</x>' AS XML).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment. I am trying to load the ssis xml file to a table and updating an attribute value by reading the xml nodes, then exporting the modified xml to local. The modified xml is running/working as expected. But,the only difference is the original file was easy to read (well formatted). Now, the formatting has changed and difficult to read and find a node (If I see from the visual studio with ViewCode option).

Comment: @p2k Is this *well formatted* content encoded as `CDATA`?

Comment: @Shungo, I can see `<property state="cdata">` and `![CDATA` some places used.

Comment: @p2k if you find *readable* parts **within** `cdata` we speak about `CDATA` sections. This will look something like this: `<![CDATA[Content goes here]]>`